# How to implement SOLID on an interface segregation

Tags: java, kotlin, coding-style, solid-principles

I have an `interface` like this :

```
interface ClientRequestListener {
    fun onLoadStub(name: String)
    fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String)
}
```

But then when implementing it on one class I just need the `onClientNeeded` is there any way to avoid having to override these two methods?
I've tried to create another interface that extends that one but still asking me to implement the methods..

### Clarification

I'm using an external library, that uses an interface with these two methods, and the thing is where I'm using this I just need one method instead of both, and instead of having an override doing anything I just wanted to know a way to avoid that extra override that I do not need.

### EDIT

```
fun doSomeMagic(name: String, clientRequestListener: ClientRequestListener? = null) =
    LibraryRequest.getClient(name)
        .withListener(object : LibraryInterface() {
            override fun onLoadStub(name: String) {
                clientRequestListener?.onLoadStub(name)
            }

            override fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String) {
                clientRequestListener?.onClientNeeded(id, email)
            }
        })
```

So when I'm using this method I do something like this :

```
doSomeMagic("Charls", object : ClientRequestListener {
  override fun onClientNeeded(name: String) {
    //I'm not doing nothing here
  }

  override fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String) {
    //Do something with the id and email
  }
})
```

So what I'd like to do is something to call only `onClientNeeded` there instead both of them.

Comment: You can add each method to a separate interface, and let your class implement only the interface with `onClientNeeded`

Comment: The thing is that I'm using a library that requires these two methods, but just on some places I want to use the `onClientNeeded` because the other one is not usefull for me

Comment: Then you have to provide an implementation for the `onLoadStub` method in an abastract class. That implmententation should simply throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You can then extend that abstract class in your implementations.

Comment: If you want you can post an answer so I can test it and mark your answer as a correct in case it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change things in a several options here:

a) You can create an abstract class which will provide default (empty) implementation of the unneeded method, and will force you to override only method you're interested in:

```
abstract class AbsClientRequestListener {
    override fun onLoadStub(name: String) {
    }
    abstract fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String)
}
```

b) If you have a hierarachy of classes, you can provide a default implementation in your base class and leave `onClientNeeded` unimplemented for the subclasses:

```
interface ClientRequestListener {
    fun onLoadStub(name: String)
    fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String)
}

abstract class BaseClient: ClientRequestListener {
    override fun onLoadStub(name: String) {
        // Leave empty
    }
}

class Client:BaseClient() {
    override fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String) {
        // Put required implementation
    }
}
```

c) Or you can just use this interface as is and provide an empty implementation every time :)

**EDIT**

In your specific case you can add class `ClientRequestListenerAdapter`:

```
abstract class ClientRequestListenerAdapter : ClientRequestListener {
    override fun onLoadStub(name: String) {
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
doSomeMagic("Charls", object : ClientRequestListenerAdapter {
  override fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String) {
    //Do something with the id and email
  }
})
```

No changes in the function `doMagic` are needed.

Comment: I'm looking for the option 2, can you provide an example? I'm just lookinf for exactly the same use an interface and use just one method of these interface, that's why I've created a BaseClientinterface only for that method but then the compiler told me that I have to override all the methods.. can you provide an example for the option 2?

Comment: @StuartDTO, added a brief hierarchy as an example.

Comment: Added also a code sniped on my question so you guys can understand better my problem, does it clear to you now?

Comment: @StuartDTO, I see. Added an edit to my post. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: well, yes at least it does not complain, but do you think this is a SOLID solution?

Comment: SOLID principles are important when you're developing classes or interfaces. Here you're stuck to use them as they are, and you can't really do much. But with this implementaton - why not?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an implementation for the onLoadStub method in an abastract class. That implmententation should simply throw an UnsupportedOperationException. You can then extend that abstract class in your implementations.

```
abstract class AbstractClientRequestListener : ClientRequestListener {
override fun onLoadStub(name: String) {
    throw UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported")
    }
}

class ClientRequestListenerImpl : AbstractClientRequestListener() {
    override fun onClientNeeded(id: String, email: String) {
       TODO("not implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add a simple example of it?

Comment: Edited my comment

Comment: Added also a code sniped on my question so you guys can understand better my problem, does it clear to you now?